# Seems unable to pull config vars from the environment (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, environment-variables

My Rails app seems unable to pull config variables from the environment. Forms work fine when credentials are hard-coded but when I try to use the environment variables it fails. What could be going wrong? I might have made a basic mistake since I'm only a newbie programmer.

I've set the environmental variables in the terminal. If I enter `heroku config` it confirms it has correctly stored the access key. Example:

```
heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<access key>
```

In my code I replace the hard-coded access key with for example:

```
ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY']
```

On the development server it now generates an error message related to the credentials. Example:

```
unable to sign request without credentials set
```

This is the same error message I get if I leave the credentials empty. So it seems that it isn't loading/initializing the environmental variables...?

If I enter `'ENV["S3_ACCESS_KEY"]'` instead of `ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY']`, I get the message: `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records`. This is the same message I get if I in the hard-coded credentials I enter a wrong credential.

Any ideas what might be wrong? What steps could I take to find the cause?

---

**Update:** Starting development with the command below, solves it. Could anyone explain how to solve this further so that I don't have to start the server that way each time? 
Should I perhaps somehow add the keys to `secrets.yml`? But I'm programming in the cloud and I would prefer it if other programmers with access to my code wouldn't see the keys.

```
S3_ACCESS_KEY=<myaccesskey> S3_SECRET_KEY=<mysecretkey> rails server
```

---

**Update 2:** If I add to `secrets.yml`:

```
secrets.yml:
development:
S3_ACCESS_KEY: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY']

Model method:
Rails.application.secrets.S3_ACCESS_KEY
```

I get the error:

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

If I instead use:

```
secrets.yml:
development:
S3_ACCESS_KEY: <my access key>

Model method:
Rails.application.secrets.S3_ACCESS_KEY
```

I get the error message:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Really don't know what else to try.

Comment: Have you check that you call Amazon S3 credentials on production.rb? And not in environments/development.rb or enviroments/test.rb.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean. Could you specify where I could check what you mean? The part of the code that uses `ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY']` writes to the S3 bucket in production as well as in development.

Comment: if is in production.rb is ok. Sometimes we forget to put in production and only have it in development which work locally but not in heroku.

Comment: Usually the credentials to connect to Amazon S3 is puted in config/environments/(production.rb/development.rb/test.rb)

Comment: I basically have none of that code in the environments folder. I have just entered `heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<access key>` in the terminal. And I have code such as `s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(` `credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']),` `region: ENV['AWS_REGION'] )` in controller and model methods.

Comment: It looks fine. Is not the environments folders problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the Heroku environment and the local development environment, which are different and unrelated. What the `heroku config:set` command does is exactly the same as putting the variables in front of the command, but it is for running the application when it is deployed to Heroku. But when you run the application on your local machine, you provide the variables in the command line.

Also, you should never expose S3 credentials to the public, such as, never commit a `secrets.yml` with the credentials into a public GitHub repo, because they will get stolen and used to run servers at your expense - [here's one article describing this situation](http://www.forbes.com/sites/runasandvik/2014/01/14/attackers-scrape-github-for-cloud-service-credentials-hijack-account-to-mine-virtual-currency/). Environment variables are a good place for the credentials.

Comment: Okay, so I think I'm starting to understand it. 1) I have added secrets.yml to .gitignore. 2) In secrets.yml I have added lines such as `S3_ACCESS_KEY: <my access key>`. 3) In methods I refer to for example: `Rails.application.secrets.S3_ACCESS_KEY`. Yeah, this works!

Comment: Have I done it correctly this way? Only thing I don't yet understand is: I program in the cloud and when I give someone else (e.g., programmer to help me) access to my code, they can just open secrets.yml and read all my keys. Am I missing something or is this normal?

Comment: @Nick `secrets.yml` under .gitignore is also a common solution. I don't know what do you mean by "in the cloud", but you should only give the keys to people you know and trust. If you want to know more about securing Amazon credentials you should study the [Identity and Access Management guide](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/).

Comment: with "in the cloud" I mean: I'm using Cloud9 (c9.io) to program. You can also use it to invite another programmer to have a look at your code to help you with it. My thought was: when you upload a key to Heroku then that programmer won't be able to see the key while you're still able to use the key, But keys you put in `secrets.yml` will be visible to the invited programmer.